# spark-submit passing python files in zip does not work

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to submit a Python Application using `spark-submit`, like so:

```
spark-submit \
    --conf spark.submit.pyFiles=path/to/archive.zip \
    --conf spark.app.name=Test123 \
    --conf spark.master=local[2] \
    --conf spark.driver.memory=5G \
    path/to/python_app.py
```

The `python_app.py` tries to import modules from `archive.zip`, but it fails with an `ModuleNotFoundError`. If I substitute

```
--conf spark.submit.pyFiles=path/to/archive.zip
```

with

```
--py-files path/to/archive.zip
```

it works as expected. It is really weird because setting master, driver memory and app name works using `--conf`.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

**Edit 2018-07-06:**
I tried this with Spark versions `2.1.3`, `2.2.0` and `2.3.1` - the problem is the same for all three versions. And: I have the problem regardless of submitting to `local[x]` or `yarn`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. I believe naming might be misleading here.

setting `spark.submit.pyFiles` states only that you want to add them to **PYTHONPATH**. But apart of that **you need to upload those files to all your executors working directory**. You can do that with `spark.files`

For me it does the job. I am setting those values in [spark-defauls.conf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)